# @font-face does not work on mobile phone

Tags: css, font-face

I use @font-faces in my CSS and added font-family properly, I embed generated fonts in folder CSS as you adviced on my server, so everything works great on my mac, but does not work on all my mobile phones: Iphone 6s+ and Samsung GalaxyS8+
http://mawdprojects.co.uk/filmPromo/siteFiles/index.html  Is there any rescue for me pls ?

Comment: `Is there any rescue for me pls ?` --> there is the duck on the bottom, use it ... he will help you

Answer (score 0):

check .ttf and .svg file was added in @font-face, for more details refer [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face), [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/), [designmodo](https://designmodo.com/font-face/)